# How can I pass the Api id from my parents to my child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, simplemodal

I am a beginner. Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge.

I succeeded in bringing Api and showing it on the screen.

Next, I would like to deliver 'idDrink' from Api's Params to the children's components.

Because I have to hand over the ID of the clicking picture to URL using 'idDrink' in the child component.

We originally set up a device that uses 'Router' to go to another page.

But I decided to make Modal instead of going to another page.

There's a problem here.

'useParams' made it easy to take over id and import API data.

But I want a modal. I thought I didn't need 'Router' because 'modal' doesn't need an address.

Please tell me if I'm wrong. And please tell me how to solve this problem.

This is Main.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
import Modal from "../Components/Modal";
import Portal from "../Components/Portal";

const Main = () => {
  const url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  async function fetchUrl() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
    setLoading(false);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
    console.log("open Modal");
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    console.log("close Modal");
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper className="main">
      {loading ? (
        "Loading..."
      ) : (
        <>
          {data.drinks.map(
           This params  ({ idDrink, strDrink, strAlcoholic, strGlass, strDrinkThumb }) => (
              <>
                <Container onClick={handleOpen}>
                  <img src={`${strDrinkThumb}`} alt={`${strDrink}`} />
                  <div key={`${idDrink}`}>{`${strDrink}`}</div>
                </Container>
                {open && (
                  <Portal> 
                    <Modal key={`${idDrink}`} onClose={handleClose} />  I want to hand over here.
                  </Portal>
                )}
              </>
            )
          )}
        </>
      )}
      <Search />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default Main;
```

This is Child Component file Modal.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Modal = ({ onClose, idDrink }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${idDrink}`;
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.drinks);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [idDrink]); 
  return (
    <MyModals onClick={onClose}>
      <Content>Detail</Content>
    </MyModals>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

The reason why I implement this feature is because of the Api address that changes every click.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you want pass the value of idDrink in your Modal component.

Use

`<Modal idDrink={idDrink} onClose={handleClose} />`

instead of  `` <Modal key={`${idDrink}`} onClose={handleClose} /> ``

in your parent component.
Hopefully you will be able to access idDrink from Modal.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use   `<Modal id_Drink={idDrink} onClose={handleClose} />`
2. Add props in your modal: const Modal = (props) => {}
3. Access idDrink in your modal: `props.id_Drink`
   , Access handleClose in your modal: `props.onClose()`